# How to efficiently loop through a MongoDB collection in order update a sequence column?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoose, sequence

I am new to MongoDB/Mongoose and have a challenge I'm trying to solve in order to avoid a performance rabbit hole!

I have a MongoDB collection containing a numeric column called 'sequence' and after inserting a new document, I need to cycle through the collection starting at the position of the inserted document and to increment the value of sequence by one. In this way I maintain a collection of documents numbered from 1 to n (i.e. where n = the number of documents in the collection), and can render the collection as a table in which newly inserted records appear in the right place.

Clearly one way to do this is to loop through the collection, doing a seq++ in each iteration, and then using Model.updateOne() to apply the value of seq to sequence for each document in turn.

My concern is that this involves calling updateOne() potentially *hundreds* of times, which might not be optimal for performance.  Any suggestions on how I should approach this in a more efficient way?

Comment: Mongo doesn't even good in-built support for sequences, so my first question would be do you really need this sequence at all?  Can you just rely on the `_id` field, which should already be unique and auto incrementing?

Comment: The reason I figured I need a separate sequence field, is that I need to add documents into my collection so that they are rendered at the right point following a predecessor document (row) when rendered as a table.  Open to other ways of achieving this, as I realize _id probably won't help me.

Comment: It is going to be very hard to do this, because there is always the chance that you might delete an item in the sequence.

Comment: True, however I was hoping to re-sequence the collection to close any gaps when necessary e.g. after a delete.  My basic requirement is to insert a row into an HTML table such that after the collection has been updated, the table can be re-rendered with the new row in the same place.

Comment: Which gets up back to my first comment.  Maybe consider not even using a Mongo sequence.

Comment: I'm a newbie ... can you point me to another approach I can research for handling this?  Right now I'm using Nodejs / EJS / Express / Bootstrap (all for the first time) and hope to use MongoDB to store/persist the data. The roadblock I've run into is how to add, edit & delete rows in my table (that part works), but to be able to persist this in my collection so that the table can grow to any size without integrity or performance issues.